# node.js как объявить структуру из node-ffi, если она есть в библиотеке

Tags: node.js

Есть библиотека, в ней определена структура (struct).
В Node.js я использую модуль node-ffi.
Так вот функции библиотеки нормально работают, но не знаю как объявить структуру из Node, чтобы получать данные.
Вот пример из мануала библиотеки:

```
LONG lUserID;
NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30 struDeviceInfo;
lUserID = NET_DVR_Login_V30("192.168.1.64", 8000, "admin", "12", &struDeviceInfo);
```

`NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30` - структура. А мне нужно получить данные исходящие из устройства в переменной `struDeviceInfo`.

Вот часть самого кода Node:

```
var net = require('net');
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');
var request = require('request');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var ffi = require("ffi");
var ref = require("ref");
var ref_struct = require("ref-struct");
var libHikSDK = ffi.Library('./libhcnetsdk.so', {
'NET_DVR_Init': ['bool', []],
'NET_DVR_SetConnectTime': ['bool', ['char', 'char']],
'NET_DVR_SetReconnect': ['bool', ['char', 'bool']],
'NET_DVR_Login_V30': ['char', ['string', 'int', 'string', 'string']],
'NET_DVR_Cleanup': ['void', []],
'NET_DVR_GetLastError': ['char', []],
'NET_DVR_GetSDKVersion': ['char',[]],
'NET_DVR_SetLogToFile': ['bool',['int', 'string']]
});

libHikSDK.NET_DVR_Cleanup();
var init = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_Init();
var v = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_GetSDKVersion();
var s = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_SetConnectTime('200000', '1');
libHikSDK.NET_DVR_SetLogToFile(3, "/home/user");
var i = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_Login_V30("192.168.0.10", 8000, "admin", "12345");
var g = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_GetLastError();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу решил. 
Даже если структура объявлена в сторонней библиотеке, все равно нужно ее объявляться в js-коде, а также инициализировать объект для этой структуры (пришлось изучать азы Си). 
При использовании node-ffi будьте внимательнее к переменным, так как иначе траблы с памятью и все летит.

```
var net = require('net');
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');
var request = require('request');
var ffi = require("ffi");
var ref = require("ref");
var Ref_struct = require("ref-struct");
var ArrayType = require("ref-array");

var ref_byte = ref.types.byte;
var devInfo = Ref_struct({
    "sSerialNumber": ArrayType(ref_byte, 48),
    "byAlarmInPortNum": ref_byte,
    "byAlarmOutPortNum": ref_byte,
    "byDiskNum": ref_byte,
    "byDVRType": ref_byte,
    "byChanNum": ref_byte,
    "byStartChan": ref_byte,
    "byAudioChanNum": ref_byte,
    'byIPChanNum': ref_byte,
    'byZeroChanNum': ref_byte,
    'byMainProto': ref_byte,
    'bySubProto': ref_byte,
    'bySupport': ref_byte,
    'bySupport1': ref_byte,
    'bySupport2': ref_byte,
    'wDevType': ref.types.int16,
    'bySupport3': ref_byte,
    'byMultiStreamProto': ref_byte,
    'byStartDChan': ref_byte,
    'byStartDTalkChan': ref_byte,
    'bySupport4': ref_byte,
    'byLanguageType': ref_byte,
    'byRes2': ArrayType(ref_byte, 9)
});
var devInfoPTR = ref.refType(devInfo);
var videoFiles = Ref_struct({
    lChannel: 'long',
    dwFileType: 'int',
    dwIsLocked: 'int',
    dwUseCardNo: 'int',
    sCardNumber: ArrayType(ref_byte, 32);
    struStartTime: 
    struStopTime:
});
var libSDK = new ffi.Library('mylib.so', {
    'NET_DVR_Init': ['bool', []],
    'NET_DVR_SetConnectTime': ['bool', ['int', 'int']],
    'NET_DVR_Cleanup': ['void', []],
    'NET_DVR_Login_V30': ['void', ['string', 'int', 'string', 'string', devInfoPTR]],
    'NET_DVR_GetLastError': ['long', []],
    'NET_DVR_SetLogToFile': ['bool',['int', 'string']],
});
libHikSDK.NET_DVR_Cleanup();
var init = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_Init();
var s = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_SetConnectTime('200000', '1');
libHikSDK.NET_DVR_SetLogToFile(3, "/dest/to/dir");
var devInfoAlloc = new devInfo();
libHikSDK.NET_DVR_Login_V30("192.168.0.10", 8000, "admin", "12345", devInfoAlloc.ref());
var g = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_GetLastError();
```